# How Can I View Glassfish Logs on Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working on making the switch from **Netbeans** to **Intellij Idea**.  One thing I miss from **Netbeans** is the ability to view the **Glassfish** server logs in real-time in the IDE.  It seems like with Idea I need to go out to the file system and tail them.

Is there another way that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Additional server logs can be added in the `"Logs tab of the Glassfish Run/Debug configuration"`

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I see messages like these, but how do I view  logger and println messages?   "C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat" start-domain --domaindir C:\Users\me personal_domain
Attempting to start personal_domain.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
[2012-09-28 08:38:13,888] Artifact this:war: Server is not connected. Press 'Deploy' to start deployment.
Connected to server
[2012-09-28 08:38:33,442] Artifact this:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2012-09-28 08:38:40,631] Artifact this:war: Error during artifact

Comment: Ah.  Just found the tab.  Got it.  Thanks.

Comment: @CrazyCoder The image is not available anymore.

Comment: @banterCZ, the image works fine, ask your ISP support or sysadmin why you can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:-

1. Go to the "Run/Debug Configuration" section
2. Go to "Logs" tab
3. Click on the "+" icon
4. Enter "Alias" name and enter the server log file location associated on the "Log File Location" section

[image: Add GlassFish server log]

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish log is available in the Services window, when you click on a running deployment, and then click the GlassFish Log tab in the right part of the window:

[image]